# if Col 2 is true copy the calues from Col1 into Col 3

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a dataset which is as follows

```
       Id   Name   Description          Status
       1    Kyla   DataMining           Yes
       2    Kim    MonteCarlo Methods   No
       3    Kanye  Meta-Analysis        May Be
       4    Bruce  Optimization         Yes
```

I am trying to create a fourth column Result which will store the values from Description column if Status == Yes, if Status == No or May Be then it will just copy the values from Status which is No or May Be. The final dataset should look like this

```
       Id   Name   Description          Status      Result
       1    Kyla   DataMining           Yes         DataMining
       2    Kim    MonteCarlo Methods   No          No
       3    Kanye  Meta-Analysis        May Be      May Be
       4    Bruce  Optimization         Yes         Optimization
```

So far I tired doing this using ifelse

```
       data1$Result <- ifelse(data1$Status == "Yes", data1$Description, data1$Status)
```

I dont get any error but I dont get the right results either, i am seeing some completely unrelated numbers ?? Need some help.

Comment: Your line seems correct to me. Provide your dataset and the results you are obtaining.

Comment: This is more of a guess than anything, but you might get strange behavior if the Description and Status variables are stored as factors.  Because it's a bit hard for me to predict when these problems will occur, I'm in the habit of making sure my string data are stored as character (rather than factor) class.  Does the result improve if you first specify data$Description = as.character(data$Description), and data$Status = as.character(data$Status)?

Comment: @nicola, every time I do dput(head(mydataset)) I see more than 5 observations., thats why I have been not able to paste my actual dataset

Comment: @MarkTPatterson, thats exactly whats going on. Changing them to character did the trick, :)

Comment: You could also match the factor levels and not need to convert to character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your variables `Description` and `Status` are stored as factors. You can see this using `str(data1)`.  Try to convert it to character first using `as.character()`.

```
data1$Status<-as.character(data1$Status)
data1$Description<-as.character(data1$Description)
```

Comment: I think you are right.  I didn't read the `i am seeing some completely unrelated numbers ?`

Comment: @Metric,  and akrun you both are correct, it was the damn factor , changing from factor to character did the trick :)